# Creating a subquery in Access

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I am attempting to create a subquery in Access but I am receiving an error stating that one record can be returned by this subquery. I am wanting to find the top 10 companies that have the most pets then I want to know the name of those pets. I have never created a subquery before so I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT TOP 10 dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency
(SELECT dbo_tPet.Pet
FROM dbo_tPet)

FROM dbo_tPet INNER JOIN dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency ON
dbo_tPet.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID =
dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID
GROUP BY dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency
ORDER BY Count(dbo_tPet.PetID) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution, requiring a subquery in the `WHERE IN ()` clause:

```
SELECT t1.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency, dbo_tPet.Pet,
FROM dbo_tPet 
INNER JOIN dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency t1 ON
dbo_tPet.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID = t1.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID    
WHERE t1.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency IN   
    (SELECT TOP 10 t2.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency
    FROM dbo_tPet 
    INNER JOIN dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency t2 ON
    dbo_tPet.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID = t2.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID
    GROUP BY t2.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency
    ORDER BY Count(dbo_tPet.Pet) DESC);
```

Table aliases are not needed but I include them for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully do it:

```
SELECT a.GovernmentRegulatoryAgency, t.NumOfPets
FROM dbo_tGovenrnmentRegulatoryAgency a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 10 p.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID, COUNT(p.PetID) AS NumOfPets
    FROM dbo_tPet p
    GROUP BY p.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID
    ORDER BY COUNT(p.PetID) DESC
) t
ON a.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID = t.GovernmentRegulatoryAgencyID
```

In a nutshell, first get the nested query sorted, identifying what the relevant agencies are, then inner join back to the agency table to get the detail of the agencies so picked.

Comment: Not disputing this answer, but worth mentioning that nested queries in Access are often fiendishly slow (a pity, because in nearly all server based systems, this is definitely not the case, and nested queries are regarded as best practice because of their clarity). You could rewrite this as a single aggregate query.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre - go on then, and test the results.